# Git Log Displays Nothing

Tags: git

I have a number of git repositories (with commits) and each displays nothing when running `git log`. If I run the command outside a project directory (without a git repository) I get:

> fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

I tried re-installing Git (I'm now running 1.7.5.4) and re-cloning my repositories to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: What does `git rev-list --all --pretty` return?

Comment: @Abe It returns stuff (author, date, message, etc).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've just experienced the same problem, of git log not displaying anything for a particular file.  The problem turned out to be Windows was displaying the directory name with an upper-case first letter, but git expected the first letter to be lower-case.  So "git log Subdir/file.c" produced no errors and no output.  Whereas "git log subdir/file.c" produced the expected revision history.

Comment: I am observing now slightly the same: under Windows, `git log` for some particular file gives an empty output, but `git diff` to the same file works fine. Other files in the same directory seem not affected.
I tried different command line options to git, but the output is still empty.

Comment: I got a solution to my issue. The problem appeared when I tried to say `git blame` to my file and it complained. Then I checked with `git branch --all` that my HEAD points to branch `main`, but I am in the branch `master`, and `master` differs from `main`. No much clue what happend, but I deleted branch `main` and moved `master` to `main`. After that manipulation everything works again for me :)

Answer (score 16):

`git log` does not show any commit!

I noticed that not only `git log` command but also `man` command does not show anything for me. 
It turned out that I just needed to set the `PAGER` environment variable to `less` or `more` programs to solve both problems.

```
export PAGER=less
```

Answer (score 5):

May be that the pager is not set up correctly with git.

**Diagnostics:**

```
git config core.pager
```

If it gives empty output or something unexpected, it may be the cause of the problem.

**Solution**

Try one of the following with xxx = more, less or other pager of choice:

```
git config core.pager xxx
git config --global core.pager xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

The fatal error for running a git command outside a project directory is expected. Not getting any log messages at all for running `git log` is not.

Try running `gitk` to see if you can see the log history there.

Comment: gitk won't show anything either. If you want to use gitk, call it with the --all parameter as you would with git log.

Comment: probably not worth a downvote since it is a troubleshooting technique but whatevs

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have any commits, it would not show anything and error. Also, if you don't have a current commit in a bare repo, you can still show all commits in a repo with `git log --all'.

You can also see what branches you have with

```
git branch -a
```

then you can `git checkout branchX`. You would be able to get output from `git log` then - provided you have some commits there. If you have bare repos, you can't checkout.

Hope this helps.

Comment: He says he has many repos, none of them have have any commit? No chance. And what do you mean by `if you don't have a current commit` ? If you are talking about detached head, it still shows a log as commits are still pointing to their parents.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem (and "git diff" doesn't work either), I still do not know why but  I workaround :

```
git rev-list --all --reverse
```

Or better (only 10 last commits with message information) :

```
git rev-list --all --max-count=10 --reverse --pretty
```

Comment: This gives the list of commits, not the commits for a specific file.

Comment: I have the same problem: git log and  git diff not working did you ever manage to resolve this?

Comment: Sorry, it was 3 years ago, I was working on Windows (now on Linux it's fine)

Answer (score 0):

i had the similar issue with a log to a file. **1**] get a list of your config `files git config --list` **2**] check this entry `core.filemode=false` change it to true `git config core.filemode true` **3**] check your files path in `gitk` **4**] i had the wrong path. now it works. `git log --  ./Documents/holdMe.txt`

Answer (score 0):

For those who still don't come up with solution:
Check your firewall, mine (Comodo on windows10) was blocking Git\usr\bin\less.exe.

After removing it from blocked apps it worked fine.