# Is there a standard place that the PAGER environment variable is set by default for all users in Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, pager

The question is simply this: how is the PAGER variable set by default for all users in Ubuntu Linux? Where is this done (in terms of a standard file or location)?

A secondary question is how might this get unset?

I have been told to use `/etc/profile` and/or `/etc/environment` to fix it, and I am experimenting with these as solutions, but **neither** of these was used to set the PAGER variable originally. Where should this have been done?

Here is the problem that led me to this question:

`man` stopped working on my Ubuntu (18.04) system a while ago. I did not notice that it had failed at first until `git log` also failed and I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50744032/646398) on fixing that. When I use the command `export PAGER=more` it fixes the problem with both `man` and `git`.

To fix the problem for me, I have added the line:

```
export PAGER=more
```

to my `.bashrc` file. It took some looking around to realize the difference between that command and just `PAGER=more`, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1158231/646398) spelled it out for me. I guess my calls to `man` and `git` are subprocesses, and adding the `export` in front is needed for them to have access to the variable. (If that is wrong, please inform me!)

Comment: Shouldn't you rather fix `less` than use the much less powerful `more`?

Comment: @BenjaminW. Sure that is a choice. But it does not address the question.

Comment: That's why it's a comment ;) Isn't [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641477/how-to-set-environment-variable-for-everyone-under-my-linux-system) the same as you're asking?

Comment: Why not `/etc/profile`?

Comment: @Rafael  I don't know if it should be `etc/profile` -- I did not avoid that _per se_ it just did not come up in my search. I guess my question then is "why is the pager **not** set here already? Is it usually set somewhere else?" It certainly is not currently set to anything in my Ubuntu 18's `/etc/profile`.

Comment: @BenjaminW. are you recommending that answer for the `/etc/profile` part or the `/etc/environment` part?

Comment: In general, if `man` is not working then you can check `man man` and read under `--pager` the following _Specify which output pager to use.  By default, man uses **`less -s`**.  This option overrides the `$MANPAGER` environment variable, which in turn overrides the `$PAGER` environment variable._. Remark that the default command depends from distribution to distribution. Oh wait, `man` is not working ... use `man --pager='less -s' man`

Comment: I just linked to the whole Q&A because the question seems to be identical. It doesn't look like there is a single correct answer – you'd have to figure out how Ubuntu does it. But `/etc` looks like a good starting point.

Comment: @kvantour Thanks for that, I did not see that before. But Ubuntu does not have the part about `less -s`.